# Javascript Random background Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, random

I have written this with the intention of randomising a background image each time a user visits a site. I had to use Ajax as the image is being used as a background image in css with some animations.

```
var images = [
  '1.jpg', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg'];

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * images.length);
var randomImage = "img/backgrounds/" + randomNumber + ".jpg";
jQuery.ajax(randomImage);

$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    $('.cover').css({ 'background-image': 'url(' + randomImage + ')' }).addClass('loaded');
});
```

My problem is that some images seem to be used a lot more often that others and image number 6 never shows?

I was hoping someone who is more comfortable in Javascript might be able to shed some light on this for me.

Thanks in advance, Sam

Comment: Try naming images from 0.jpg to 5.jpg

Comment: or `Math.floor(Math.random() * (images.length + 1))`

Comment: Thanks Guys, I ended up implementing something simular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your random number as 
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length)+1);

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The range of variable `randomNumber` is `0` to `5` (inclusive). They are the indexes where you want to fetch the value from the array `images`:

```
var randomImage = "img/backgrounds/" + images[randomNumber];
```